# Set global font size for all children in box layout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've got three buttons in a box layout in Kivy. I want each of them to have the same fontsize. Is there a way to specify the font size for all widgets within a box layout, instead of having to define the font size in the child widgets?

This box layout's part of the .kv file looks like this

```
BoxLayout:
    id: action_buttons
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "100dp" 
    
    Button:
        id: cust_query
        text: "Send Custom Query"
        font_size: 24

    Button:
        id: man_query
        text: "Manually Check Tables"
        font_size: 24

    ToggleButton:
        id: sched_query
        text: "Start Query Schedule"
        on_state: root.schedule_switch_state(self)
        font_size: 24
```

Is there a way to do this more like so:

```
BoxLayout:
    id: action_buttons
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "100dp"
    font_size: 24    
    
    Button:
        id: cust_query
        text: "Send Custom Query"

    Button:
        id: man_query
        text: "Manually Check Tables"

    ToggleButton:
        id: sched_query
        text: "Start Query Schedule"
        on_state: root.schedule_switch_state(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution : `font_size: self.parent.font_size`

in `*.kv`

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<Main>:
    
    BoxLayout:
        id: myboxlayout
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: root.size
        font_size: 24
        
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
            font_size: self.parent.font_size
        
        Button:
            text: "Button 2"
            font_size: self.parent.font_size
```

first set a font size for the boxlayout

then point the fontsize of the button to their parent's fontisze

// hope this help : )

Comment: yay nice : ) 